# Mistake in the proof of the volume of a torus

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification, volume

We define the function $$f(x)=\sqrt{r^2-(x-R)^2}$$
which graphs a semi-circle with radius $r$ with its center being at $(R,0)$
If we were to rotate this function around the $y$-axis, we'd get half a torus, thus, the formula for the volume of a tors with radii $r$ and $R$ would be $$2\pi\int\limits_{R-r}^{R+r}\left(f(x)\right)^2dx=2\pi\int\limits_{R-r}^{R+r}\left(r^2-x^2-R^2+2xR\right)dx=2\pi\left[xr^2-\frac{x^3}{3}-R^2x+Rx^2\right]_{R-r}^{R+r}$$
This simplifies to $$\left(Rr^2+r^3-\frac{(R+r)^3}{3}-R^3-R^2r+R(R+r)^2\right)-\left(Rr^2-r^3-\frac{(R-r)^3}{3}-R^3+R^2r+R(R-r)^2\right)$$
$$2r^3+\frac{(R-r)^3-(R+r)^3}{3}-2R^2r+4R^2r$$
$$2r^3+\frac{-2r^3-6R^2r}{3}+2R^2r$$
$$\frac{4}{3}r^3\Rightarrow\frac{8\pi r^3}{3}$$
which has no dependence on $R$. This cannot be correct. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Aren't you missing a term from the shells formula?  $\int_a^b 2\pi xf(x) \ dx$?  You seem to be using disks/washers, but that would require you to go around the $x$-axis if you're keeping everything in $x$s.  Or am I misinterpreting your method?

Comment: @Randall I think you're right!

Comment: @Randall oh shit you're right, I'll recalculate it correctly and post my answer as a solution if no one answers by then. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I think the correct integral would be $4\pi \int_{R-r}^{R+r} x \sqrt{r^2-(x-R)^2} \ dx$ which might not be fun to do.

Comment: @Randall Make a hint or an answer for the OP. +)